# Is there a name for the curve $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = k$

Tags: geometry, functions

Is there a name for the curves for which

1. $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = k$
2. $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} = \pm k$

Here's a picture. The regions are 1, and 2 with each of $k$ and $-k$.

[image: What is it????!!?!?!?!]

Comment: These have been called polyellipse and (I guess) polyhyperbola, respectively, for the norm $p=1/2$.  See [here](http://www.emis.de/journals/AMAPN/vol31_1/31_09.pdf).

Comment: My (old!) copy of the _CRC Standard Mathematical Tables_ (15th edition -- 1967), in the "Curves and Surfaces" section, shows $ \ \pm x^{1/2} \ \pm \ y^{1/2} \ = \ a^{1/2} \ $ simply as a type of parabola -- no special name for it otherwise.  The quantity $ \ a \ $ is the distance from the origin to either of the tangent points with the coordinate axes; the focus lies at the midpoint of the segment connected said tangent points.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner It looks pretty much identical to the parabola $(1+x^2)/2$ rotated about the origin by 45 degrees.

Comment: It also appears to be a "cousin" of curves such as the "astroid" $ \ x^{2/3} \ + \ y^{2/3} \ = \ a^{2/3} \ $ .  (I don't know if this is also a member of the generalized conics **vadim123** cites -- I am not familiar with them.)  Playing with the signs of the terms presents the same sort of behavior as your curve, although the segments do not "join up" smoothly.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner yeah, the blue part is common to this and "star shaped" thing with four points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q 1.$\sqrt x +\sqrt y=k\implies$ $ x+y+2\sqrt {x y}=k^2\implies$ $2\sqrt {x y}=k^2-(x+y)\implies$ $$\implies4 x y=k^4+(x+y)^2-2 k^2 (x+y)........(1).$$

Make a change to the orthogonal co-ordinate system $(u,v)$ where $u+v=x\sqrt 2$ and $u-v=y\sqrt 2.$  (The co-ordinate axes with respect to $(u,v)$ are the lines $x\pm y=0.$)

We have $x y=(u^2-v^2)/2$ and $x+y=u\sqrt 2.$

So (1) implies $2(u^2-v^2)=k^4+2 u^2-2 k^2 u\sqrt 2$, which simplifies to $$-2v^2=k^4-2k^2 u \sqrt 2........(2).$$ For $k\ne 0$ this is a parabola.

Comment: Executive summary: The name for the curve is "parabola".

Comment: The a hyperbola $xy=k$ is called a rectangular hyperbola, as, I assume, it's contained by the coordinate axes, rather than the diagonals. I wonder if (un-)rectangular parabola is a suitable name here.

Comment: No: the name "parabola" does definitely need no prefix or suffix.

Comment: Every  parabola has two tangent lines that meet at  right angle. All parabolas are geometrically similar.